# Differential Equation Proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the constant coefficient equation

$$L(y) = y'' + fy' + gy = 0$$

Let m be the solution satisfying

$$m(x) = 1, m'(x) = 0$$

and let $n(X)$ be the solution satisfying

$$n(x) = 0, n'(x) = 1.$$

If $z$ is a solution satisfying
$$z(x) = a, z'(x) = b$$

Show that:

$$z(x) = m(x)a + n(x)b$$
for all x.

How would you approach this since the constants are unknown? 
I'm actually not even sure how to use the any of the given info about m, n, z

Comment: Do you mean that $m(0)=1$, $m'(0)=1$ as initial values? Won't satisfy the differential equation otherwise

Comment: Differentiation is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean $m(0)=1$ and $m'(0)=1$ as initial values, question doesn't make sense otherwise.

Since $z(x) = m(x) a + n(x) b$, we have the following:

$$z'(x) = m'(x) a + n'(x) b \\ z''(x) = m''(x) a + n''(x) b$$

Since $m(x)$ and $n(x)$ are assumed to satisfy the differential equation, we have

\begin{align*}
L[z]= z'' + f z' + g z &= ( m''(x) a + n''(x) b) + f (m'(x) a + n'(x) b) \\
  &= a (m''(x) + f m'(x) + g m(x) ) + b (n''(x) + f n'(x) + g n(x) ) \\
 &= a \cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 \\
 &= 0
\end{align*}

Therefore, $z(x)$ also satisfies the differential equation.

Given initial conditions $z(0) = a$ and $z'(0) = b$, we can satisfy the initial value problem using the derivatives we computed above:
$$z(0) = a \cdot m(0) + b \cdot n(0) = a \cdot 1 + b \cdot 0 = a \\
 z'(0) = a \cdot m'(0) + b \cdot n'(0) = a \cdot 0 + b \cdot 1 = b$$

Therefore, $z(x)= a \cdot m(x) + b \cdot n(x)$ satisfies the initial value problem $L[y]=0$ with $y(0) = a$ and $y'(0) = b$.

Comment: Yes, sorry! m(x) should be m(0) and same for n.
For the second step, why is it necessary to show z(x) satisfies the differential equation?

Comment: We want to show that $z(x)$ solves the differential equation $L[y]=0$ as well as the initial conditions, thus solving the initial value problem. Therefore, we need to verify both.